# MacOS Terminal command to show all hidden file in finder

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

as in the title, what is the command to show all hidden files in Finder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true
```

as bonus, you might love to have the full path shown in the title bar as well

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool true
```

don't forget

```
killall Finder
```

for them to take effects